# bilateral filter in residuel image

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, filter

i went to applicate the bilateral filter in residuel image (residel image=image origianle-image with weavlet transform)
the errer is

> Error using bfilter2 (line 35)
>   Input image A must be a double precision matrix of size NxMx1
>   or NxMx3 on the closed interval [0,1].
>
> i tried to normalizate my data with:

```
 f = rand(256,256)
normf = max(f) - min(f);               % this is a vector
normf = repmat(normf, [length(f) 1]);  % this makes it a matrix
                                       % of the same size as A
normalizedf = f./normf;
```

*the  valuue in matrix become betwen [0,1] but the error still the same 
NB:the bilateral filter taht i use is B = bfilter2(A,W,SIGMA) performs 2-D bilateral filtering for the grayscale or color image A. A should be a double precision matrix of size NxMx1 or NxMx3 (i.e., grayscal or color images, respectively) with normalized values in the closed interval [0,1]. The half-size of the Gaussian bilateral filter window is defined by W. The standar deviations of the bilateral filter are given by SIGMA, where the spatial-domain standard deviation is given by SIGMA(1) and the intensity-domain standard deviation is given by SIGMA(2).*
NB:the size of my image is <256x256 double>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to know whats going on as you dont show much code, but if you go to `bwfilter2` you can see the next piece of code:

```
if ~isfloat(A) || ~sum([1,3] == size(A,3)) || ...
      min(A(:)) < 0 || max(A(:)) > 1
   error(['Input image A must be a double precision ',...
          'matrix of size NxMx1 or NxMx3 on the closed ',...
          'interval [0,1].']);      
end
```

That's where you get the error. I would suggest you test each of the conditions of the if (i.e `~isfloat(A)` , `min(A(:)) < 0` ,...) in your data, and see which ones becomes `1` and throws the error.

Comment: i tested your proposition and the error was 'interval [0,1].'] so how can i normalized my value ,i used this code but i don't know why it is wrong  f = rand(256,256)
normf = max(f) - min(f);               % this is a vector
normf = repmat(normf, [length(f) 1]);  % this makes it a matrix
                                       % of the same size as A
normalizedf = f./normf;

Comment: You are forgetting to substract min(f) from f before the division. Thats your problem @هاجرجمعة

Comment: thanks a lot :) i do this ,it works but i don't know if the preincipe is right can you give me your opinnion ,thanks  again @ander biguri                  , f = rand(256,256)
normf = max(f) - min(f);               % this is a vector
normf = repmat(normf, [length(f) 1]);  
        
j = repmat(min(f), [length(f) 1]);
k = f- j;
normalizedff = k./normf;

Comment: @هاجرجمعة yup, that should be right ;). Dont forget to  acccept the answer if you liked it ;)

Comment: thinks a gain a lotttttttt :)